# Session does not close if "close session" is given in openfiles

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I am using openfiles option in computer management from my windows 8 and windows server 2008 pc etc.

In that session tab shows current active sessions. So if i right click on any session and click on "close session" then connection form that PC to my pc gets closed. It works fine for me.

But i have a windows 7(64 bit) OS PC. If i keep some folders of my PC open from this windows 7 PC then my PC does shows active connection as normal. But if i try to close session of that windows 7 pc from my windows 8 or windows server 2008 pc then connection gets closed once, but it again reconnects automatically and i can again see that pc in sessions list. So the windows 7 pc gets connected automatically to my pc. why does this happen? Please help me to troubleshoot this.

In the image below PC83 is windows 7 pc which reconnects automatically if i close session also.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess this happens because it is intended.

Explorer won't give up after a single failure.  It will retry the connection.

Comment: But from all other pc connection gets closed and does not reconnect automatically.